# Large tiff file is not inserting

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, tiff, clob

I have a function, which has some parameter. One of the parameter is clob where i'm passing a tiff file from front end screen. In front end the tiff data is embedded in xaml and calling the function. I'm trying to store the tiff file into a table. i can able to insert tiff has length less than 32768. When i try to insert more than that its not inserting into the table. I can't even try to find the length of the file. It shows nothing. i have tried put it in bind variable and execute immediate the insert statement. nothing inserted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_tiff_data
(
as_fno      varchar2(10),
as_a_code      IN amc.amc_code%TYPE,
as_app_sign clob,
as_sataus        IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
--declared variables here
BEGIN
ls_file := as_a_code || '_' || as_fno || '.TIF';

BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO ll_count
          FROM tiff_data
         WHERE filename = ls_file AND
               image_type = 'S' AND
               fid = as_fno;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            raise_application_error(-20780,
                        excep);
            ll_count := 0;
    END;
    IF ll_count >= 1 THEN
        RETURN 'Z';
    ELSE
        IF length(as_app_sign) > 0 THEN
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO tiff_data
                    (filename,
                     image_type,
                     amc_code,
                     fid,
                     image_date,
                     image,
                     editor_id,
                     xy_cor)
                VALUES
                    (ls_file,
                     'S',
                     as_a_code,
                     as_fno,
                     SYSDATE,
                    plf_base64_clob_to_blob(as_app_sign),
                     '',
                     '');
                IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN
                    RETURN 'Y';
                ELSE
                    RETURN 'C';
                END IF;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    raise_application_error(-20781,
                                excep);
                    RETURN 'D';
            END;
        
        
        END IF;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise_application_error(-20782,
                    excep);
        RETURN 'E';
END;
RETURN 'F';
END insert_tiff_data;
```

I think function abnormally closed when trying to access that variable **as_app_sign**.

Comment: What return value do you get - maybe the file just already exists in the table? Or do you get an exception? (Not relevant, but the code in your exception handlers after you raise can't be reached; and why are you using CLOB rather than BLOB?)

Comment: @Alex Poole hi sir. thanks for the response.No exception is throwing. No, file is not already exist. inserting column has blob datatype. When i try to use plsql developer test window to check the function by passing the string length more than 32768, throwing error that string literal too long. `declare
v clob;
begin
v:='string>32768';
select insert_tiff_data('5282659','T',v,'') from dual;
end;` instead that string,less than that is working. if i replace clob instead blob in function, i'm getting an error that **wrong number or types of arguments in call to function**

Comment: You're trying to copy and paste the content of your tiff file as a string? Using a string at all sounds wrong, but you'll hit that 32k limit anyway, with the function not being called at all, unless you construct a CLOB in an anonymous block.

Comment: You probably have the same issue passing the file data from your front and xaml. No idea how you're doing that, language, tools etc; but you need to look at how the function call is being made. It isn't a problem in the function anyway - the problem is how you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the the Oracle supplied package [DBMS_LOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600), for processing a large object (blob, clob, ...). If your data exceeds 32767 bytes, you will need to build it up in segments. (32767 is the largest block size that can be transmitted at one time).  

You also have a issue with your exception handling. Raise_Application_Error immediately terminates the current block with the error code and message specified, any code following, passing that to the exception block or the exception block of any higher block or out of the procedure, any code after RAE in the same block is not executed. Thus your function is incapable or returning D or E or setting ll_count to 0. Further a return statement executed immediately exits the procedure and no following code is executed. I have not exhaustive validated, but I do not think the current function is capable of returning F either. I have put together a fiddle for [demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04d70f609eb6cd33ef82580354236d00). It patterns itself after your logic (using parameters for values), but probably does not get the logic exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the response sir. Actually there is another table which has same clob column, the file from FE  is inserting in that table. We are just select clob_col into var1 from t1; and try to insert into tiff_data table. When i try to insert >32k in anonymous block and test window its working.But when i run from front end its not working, but inserting in table t1 from front end.  In anonymous or test window i can find length of the file `dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.getlength(as_app_sign));----->58752`  This is so weird.